# How can I connect this circuit (pictured below) to my raspberry pi without using the gpio headers?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, hardware, battery, wiring

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to connect this circuit to my raspberry pi without using the gpio headers because I am trying to make a portable tablet with the raspberry pi 2 and the adafruit PiTFT plus 3.5in? Thanks! [image: Adafruit Micro Lipo w/MicroUSB Jack - USB LiIon/LiPoly charger]

Comment: It would help if you told us what the board is and does? t appears to be a boost converter/charger for the LiPo which you intend to use to power your project but that is only a guess.

Comment: The raspberry pi does not have a space for a lipo battery to connect (correct me if I'm wrong) and this board makes it so a raspberry pi can connect to a battery.

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to find out is how to make a wireless portable raspberry pi.

Comment: That is not what your question asks! Have you done a google search for Raspberry Pi tablet? Not to mention from your comment you are not even sure what the board you mention does.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Please be so kind to edit **all available and relevant* information, e.g. as discoverd in the discussion with Steve directly into the question (you can edit your own question!). Nobody will read all to comments and try to figure out which parts are current and which are not. Call for re-open after editing the question.

Comment: BTW: I almost forget. You're battery reads 150 mAh meaning you won't have much fun with your Pi. Check here for the numbers: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/14214/19949

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that my assumption that this is intended to be a power supply for your Pi, You could simply cut a micro USB cable in half and solder the 5 volt and ground wires to the matching pins on the circuit board.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50294/discussion-on-answer-by-steve-robillard-how-can-i-connect-this-circuit-pictured).