# UPS for Raspberry Pi and router (TPLINK TD-W8961)

Tags: power, battery

I have started hosting a website on my raspberry pi, but because of the power outages, and mostly because I'm itching for a DIY project I would like to build a UPS for my pi and my router(12v-1,5A).

I have done some research and I found [this](http://www.incpak.com/tech/mini-ups-system-for-routermobile-charger-diy-project/), but I have no idea if this will work and I can't risk anything because pi's are really rare and expensive around here in Turkey (I know, it sux).

Has anyone built an UPS for a Pi? Do you have any blueprints? What should I consider?

Thanks

Comment: Wow, this seems fun. I would guess that running the Pi from a battery that you are constantly charging would solve the problem, but maybe not for the router. Anyway, doing this _will_ put your equipment at risk. Think and test carefully before you plug anything in.

Comment: Possible copy of http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1360/how-do-i-build-a-ups-like-battery-backup-system by the way.

Comment: @Bex i have read http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1360/how-do-i-build-a-ups-like-battery-backup-system but it doesn't cover the modem

Comment: That project seems fine to me. Just note that it's quite inefficient to use a 7805 to generate the 5v for the Pi. As it will burn away the other 7v and turn it into heat. If the Pi is using 500mA, that will mean 3.5W of energy loss. You also need a big heatsink for the voltage regulator. Better would be to go with a switching power supply. Something like a phone-charger for your car. Also note that the battery voltage is between around 10.5 and 13.4 volt. I don't think your router will mind, but it is a risk.

Comment: Hosting anything on the RPi is a silly idea, but if you really decided to give it a go, there are plenty of hosting companies around the globe, that would gladly accept your RPi, give it an uninterrupted power supply, 100Mbps network connection and a nice refrigerated room to cool it down.

Comment: By the time you source the parts, it might be cheaper to just buy a standard, off-the-shelf UPS, and use the Network UPS Tools (NUT) package to allow a Pi to shut itself down when the power goes out. I have just posted an article I wrote with step-by-step instructions for setting it up: https://melgrubb.wordpress.com/2014/09/05/raspberry-pi-home-server-part-15power-failures/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it so rare then do not risk making your own sub standard UPS.

Go and find a cheap UPS (like a used on from eBay or something) - It doesn't need to be new since the Pi and router will only use about 5-15 watts. If you find one without a USB port then just plug your devices into the UPS.

Even the smallest UPS will be able to power your router and Pi for hours if not days and its built with quality assurance and other protection inside.