# Backup power for pi 2 model b

Tags: power, power-supply, usb-power, backup

I'm developing a CCTV system out of a pi 2 modal b and everything is on track using noIR camera and stuff. Since a CCTV should work for few hours without power, I'm in need of a backup power source when the mains are off.

Is there any circuit where I could plugin my regular power source an if that is out, a backup battery would get activated. I've seen USB batteries which is usable in this scenario but, that would need manually to switch the power source.

Comment: Buy an UPS (Uninterruptible Power Supply),

Comment: That's too costly for me! any simple solutions?

Comment: That is the simple solution!

Comment: There's no getting around buying additional hardware here, since you need 1) An alternative power source, 2) An intermediate circuit for "uninterruptedly" switching the supply when mains fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Uninterruptible Power Supply UPS**

(Just as joan suggested in the comments). There are numerous solutions available - ranging from simple to expensive.

See:

- [How do I build a UPS-like - battery backup - system?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1360/how-do-i-build-a-ups-like-battery-backup-system)
- ModMyPi's [UPS PICO](http://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi/breakout-boards/pi-modules/ups-pico)

Answer (score 1):

I bought it directly from manufacturer [www.pimodules.com](http://www.pimodulescart.com/shop/item.aspx?itemid=5)

Works very good, supply up to 2A + many extras.